# how to assign three intents to one button?

Tags: android, button, android-intent, onclicklistener

I currently have three buttons with one intent on each. A button to call, a button to send a text, and a button to voice record. I would like to turn this into one button where it starts the record function, sends the text, then makes the call. Is this possible and how so?

Here is what my current three button working code looks like:

```
package com.billyware.alert;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;



public class MainActivity extends Activity {

protected static final int ACTIVITY_RECORD_SOUND = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button doSomethingButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    doSomethingButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent phoneCall = new Intent (Intent.ACTION_CALL,   Uri.parse("tel:999"));
            startActivity(phoneCall);

        }
    });
    Button textButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button2);
    textButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent textPeople = new Intent (Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.parse("smsto:15594254565"));
            textPeople.putExtra("sms_body","Im nervous");
            startActivity(textPeople);


        }
    });
    Button recButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button3);
    recButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent recButton = new Intent(MediaStore.Audio.Media.RECORD_SOUND_ACTION);
            startActivityForResult(recButton, ACTIVITY_RECORD_SOUND);

        }
    });


}
```

}

Comment: you are trying to do something crazy from user experience prospective. try to have one piece do one work only.

Comment: @javanator im trying to create a one button alert app so if you feel your in trouble you press the button and it does all three functions is it possible?

Comment: you want to execute one by one??

Comment: @naddy yes i want to execute one by one with one button

Comment: How can you call someone and send a text and even record simultaneously??

Comment: @naddy I want the button to start the record function first then send the text then finally make the call i know the call would have to be last I was thinking I could make some kind of conditon statement for this to work

Comment: do you want it to start record on first click, send text on second click and so on..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not good at from user experience prospective that is already said @Javanator. So if you want to do this thing one by one, it will also be hazardous thing for users. 
The best way to solve this problem is to use a background service. When a user click on a button it will automatically run other works in the background that is not painful for the users. I think it is one of the best solution for this problem. Thanks.

Comment: can i create the background service and still have the elements record text call?

Comment: Why not? You can record the text call from background service.

Comment: im talking activate and start the voice record feature then send the Pre written text to designated number then call designated number while still the recording the call? @androidcodehunter

Comment: It is possible. First start a service when user click on a button. This service runs continuously in the background. In the service class you have to write the designated phone number calling code and start recording code. After completing record (for this purpose you can use a ui button to stop the record), you can stop the service. Just follow the steps. Hope it can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, such a thing is handled at the back end i.e sever side. When user clicks the button, your "central command" can be notified and that can handle sending out email and SMS and making a call. Since the recording is the only thing that can't be handled from server side, you can just do recording at the client end i.e on the device and offload the remaining tasks to the server side.

HTH.